# How to use Callout for points on Graphics objects?

Tags: graphics, labeling

`Callout` is a relatively recent functionality that is pretty useful to add custom labels to points and plots. A minimal example of it being used in `ListPlot` is

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, Callout[{1, 1}, "Cool label"], {2, 2}}]
```

[image]

What I am looking for is the same exact functionality, but for points in `Graphics` objects. I'm looking for a good way to do the above with points drawn with something like

```
Graphics[{Point@{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}}}]
```

Unfortunately, naive guesses such as `Point@Callout[{0,0},"ASD"]`, `Callout[Point@{0,0}]` don't seem to work. The documentation of `Callout` also doesn't mention any example using `Graphics` object, which makes me thing the functionality simply isn't implemented for `Graphics`.

Is there a good way to still do the above? Of course, I could "hack it" by having the callout drawn in a `ListPlot`, and then put in the embedding `Graphics` via `Show`. Something like:

```
Show[
  Graphics[
    Point@{0, 0},
    PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 2], Frame -> True
  ],
  ListPlot[
    {Callout[{0, 0}, "Cool label"]},
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity@0]
  ]
]
```

[image]

does what it should, but isn't exactly "nice".
Is there a better way to achieve this?
It doesn't have to be a solution with `Callout`; similar functionality using something else would also be fine. As long as it doesn't require manually drawing and positioning label and connecting line.

Comment: Perhaps `Text` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann is there a way to have it generate the line connecting the text to a given point?

Comment: @gIS Probably not I think. You have to define it.

Comment: Related: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2357939

Answer (score 6):

Please note that with `Show` you don't *embed* `ListPlot` graphics into a `Graphics` object, but *combine* both of them into a single `Graphics` object.

Positioning of the callouts by `ListPlot` depends on `AspectRatio`, `PlotRange`, `PlotRangePadding` and the style settings for the plot marker. By setting the target values of these options explicitly, you get the desired "nice" appearance:

```
Show[ListPlot[{Callout[{0, 0}, "Cool label"]},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 2], PlotRangePadding -> None,
   PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[2]] /. _Point -> Nothing,
 Graphics[Point@{0, 0},
  PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 2]],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: output]

In principle, you could write your own "callout primitive" using `Inset` as follows:

```
Clear[callout]
callout[point_, label_, markerSize_ : 2] := 
 Inset[ListPlot[{Callout[{0, 0}, label]}, ImageSize -> All, 
    Axes -> False, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[markerSize]] /. _Point -> Nothing, 
  point]
```

Examples of use:

```
Graphics[{Point[{{1, 1}}], callout[{1, 1}, "Cool label", 1]}, 
 Frame -> True]

Graphics[{Point[{{1, 1}}]}, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> callout[{1, 1}, "Cool label", 1]]
```

> [image: output1]

> [image: output2]

Comment: so the solution is to trick Mathematica into drawing the callouts in a ListPlot and then put the result in the desired Graphics anyway? Ideally, I was hoping for some way to directly access whatever algorithm Mathematica is using under the hood to draw and position lines and labels of `Callout`s, but I suppose there might be no easy way to access that

Comment: @glS Yes, I think `ListPlot` is the easiest way to access the label positioning algorithm.